# Android facebook sdk kiosk mode logout

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, logout, kiosk-mode

How can I develop a kiosk mode app which will be used for many different facebook users. Each one could have logout by my app and not by the official facebook app cause they will not have access to the official facebook app.

In response, a facebook employ told me this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/696057353756212

any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you're building a kiosk app, you don't want to use SSO, since you cannot control who's logged into the Facebook app.

If you're using the LoginButton, it's as easy as doing something like:

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

And when your app exits, just do a closeAndClearTokenInformation() as you've already alluded to.

What SUPPRESS_SSO does is it will only bring up a web dialog for users to log in, and will bypass the Facebook app altogether.

Comment: dumb question, what is a kiosk app?

Comment: It's an app that lives in a kiosk, think "photo booth that can share to facebook".